# Method search (model) framework Yii

Tags: php, search, yii

The question is very direct.

How can I use the method search created by Gii on framework Yii.

It created one for each Model.

Here is example

```
public function search()
{
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id_person',$this->id_person);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        $criteria->compare('data_start',$this->data_start,true);
        $criteria->compare('date_end',$this->date_end,true);
        $criteria->compare('score',$this->score);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
}
```

Is it something like "search for the person with id='x' and return her score"?
If so, I write a query?
If possible, provide an example. I'm learning Yii and don't know much. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate controller with `Gii`, you can find an example on admin page. `CGridView` is populated with search method's return value, which is `CActiveDataProvider`

Data provider is wrapper around array of models, it has additional features like pagination.

In `admin` action you can see that model is filled with GET parameters, later that model calls `search()` (in admin view). This way use can use GET to filter data provider results.

I hope it helped a bit, ask if you still have troubles.

Comment: You mean that site demo when I execute yiic webapp [...]? I didn't find actionAdmin :/

Comment: When you generate model in Gii you can generate controller with full CRUD based on that model, than you will have admin action